# Does iTunes 11 need extra services or tools to manage duplicates in the library?

Tags: itunes, windows

In the new version of iTunes 11 the find duplicates option is gone and I don't want to revert to iTunes 10 to get that function back.

I know I had 1 GB of duplicates in iTunes 10, but I can't have iTunes show them to me anymore. My first thought was wondering if iTunes 11 finds/delete/merge them automagically?

I mean, I know that I had two versions of "Lemon Tree", one is the original one and the other is a cover, but now I can't find the cover anymore. The same with other covers.

I ran http://www.macroplant.com/meta-tunes/, and I only found 3 duplicates, while I am sure I had 100+ duplicates, because last sunday I imported a lot of songs and the "find duplicates" found 800 MB.

If anyone has insight into what iTunes 11 does when upgrading a library that would be a great start, but I'd prefer an ongoing plan to keep my library minimally duplicated.

Comment: Anyone with an interest in this - please head over to meta and weigh in - http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1511/fanboy-editing-radically-change-the-author-intention

Comment: @bmike perfect edit! I'm not a native English speaker and I don't express my thougth correcly - that's perfect

Comment: Awesome - I will bend over backwards to help non-native speakers. Also - thanks to all for bearing with the process where both assumptions and wording gets challenged.

Comment: I believe Apple has indicated that view duplicates will be added back to an upcoming patch and that the absence of this tool is a temporary change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With iTunes 11.0.1, Apple restored the Find Duplicates functionality in the new iTunes.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I found 160 duplicates with dupeGuru.

But, none of them can be found in iTunes, even if they are in the hard drive.

Look: I have two identical copies of the same song on my hdd (same artist, same bitrate, same duration, different album), but when I search it in iTunes I can't find it.

[image: missing]

It looks like iTunes found duplicated songs and removed them from the library (without removing them from the hard drive, though)

Maybe that's why tools that scan the iTunes library file won't find duplicates, while tools that ignore the library file and scan the folder will find a lot of them.

I arrived to the conclusion that iTunes will "hide" songs if it thinks that it's an **exact** duplicate.

More proof. I got two identical songs from iTunes store in 2010 (The same song in two different albums)
One of them is on the HDD but can't be found in iTunes

[image: dupe]

Or, again:

[image: again]

But, when there are too many differences, like 1 second in duration, or an "à" that become an "a", the entry is kept:

[image: but]

That's why Apple "removed" the "find duplicates" menu: it's done silently and automatically - no need to search for them. (Though, the file gets "lost" in the HDD, wasting space...)

Comment: The [WhatSizeMac app](http://whatsizemac.com) does similar file duplicate searches and could work for Mac users that seek a similar answer. It's not targeted at iTunes, but you could use it only on that. It also does many great file space usage measurements as that's the primary function as software.

Comment: I found that other duplicates with different length are not merged/hidden and can be found in the library

Comment: Many libraries have either un-imported or removed, but not deleted songs lurking in them. Smarter tools look at file metadata like [ID3 tags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3) and you can always "re-import" your Music folder into iTunes and it will incorporate all "missing" files so you can then dedupe by looking over the library itself.

Comment: I _want_ to add some duplicates (one in a compilation, another in the original album) but iTunes simply won't. Did you find where the duplicate is stored in the HD?

Comment: They are stored in the library folder

Answer (score 0):

Might be interesting to find out what happened to your tracks. On my Mac there still is a huge list of duplicates (which is exactly how I want it to be).

[image]

Comment: I think there will be some interesting discoveries as people realize what changed with iTunes 11. I am curious if the Match service or even the app now does the right thing when a true duplicate is offered.

Comment: It looks maybe I was using the search wrongly? I searched for "Ligabue" (an Italian singer) and I was selecting the "album view", instead of "show it in music". When in Album/Artist view, duplicates gets merged?

Comment: When I chose "show in music", I found duplicates, instead

Comment: Maybe your search was limited to the current playlist or album initially?

Comment: It looks like I was searching wrongly, I am finding duplicates that aren't found by meta-tunes, Maybe it does not read the iTunes 11 database correctly.

Comment: I retract my comment, something strange is happening